# How to load all images from a resource file in C#?

Tags: c#, image, resources

I am new to C# and I would like to know if I can read/load all the contents of my resource file, which contains some images. I know I can do it one by one by doing something like

```
Image img = Image.FromFile("myPic.png");
```

or even loop throught it and just pass in the image name using a String[], but I want to know if there is a better and faster way to read/load in a bunch of images from my resource file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if you put your resources into a resx file like the one you find in the Property folder of your project (or create a new one) than you can compile it as an Embedded Resource and use ResXFileCodeGenerator as tool to compile it

this way you can access directly your image because it's compiled as a class that has properties with the name you use in the resource

e.g. if you have a winform project called Test and you add resource to the default Resources.resx in the Property folder, you can access a "clipboard_icon" resource as

```
global::Test.Properties.Resources.clipboard_icon;
```